# MongoDb ODBC driver -> SQL Server linked server query fails

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, odbc

I have MongoDb 3.4 installed and trying to get its data from SQL Server 2019 dev. edition using a linked server.

I managed to install the MongoDb ODBC driver and MongoDB Connector for BI 2.13 and connect it to SQL Server.

Linked server's query work fine through openquery like this:

```
select * 
from openquery([MONGOtst],  'select active,created_at,city,CAST(total_xp AS integer) from content.users' )
```

Questions are:

1. Why does it fail when I try this

   ```
   select 
       active, created_at, city, xp, status, last_action_at,
       cast(total_xp AS integer) 
   from MONGOtst.content.users
   ```

   with msg:

   > Invalid object name 'MONGOtst.content.users'

   I tried different ways `MONGOtst...users`, `MONGOtst..users`, `MONGOtst..content.users` etc. but all of them fail
2. `total_xp` at prev. query couldn't be used as is in query (maybe as it is `BSON.Decimal128`) with msg

   > The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MONGOtst" supplied invalid metadata for column "total_xp". The precision exceeded the allowable maximum.

   and I didn't find any option to restrict `BSON.Decimal128` numbers precision in driver's options as for ex. VARCHAR: *--maxVarcharLength 8000*

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're querying the mongotst through SQLServer, you'll need to use OPENQUERY for each query you run against mongotst. Alternatively, you can insert the query into a temp table, then just query off of the temp table.

   select *
   into #M
   from openquery([MONGOtst],  'select active,created_at,city,cast(total_xp AS 
   Decimal(#,#) from 
   content.users' )

I'm not too familiar with MongoDB, but I don't believe you can change precision on your ODBC driver. Someone is welcome to correct me, but the ODBC Driver is just establishing the connection and projecting the data. Not transforming any data between the connections.

2. I have a suspicion using Integer as your datatype is one of your issues since you're converting from a Decimal datatype. Either Decimal, Numeric, or Varchar should work for you. I prefer converting the datatype in the original query rather than the subquery, but either should work. Also choose whatever datatype will work best for your data.

   Select CAST(total_xp as varchar(###)) as MTotal_xp, *
   into #M
   from openquery([MONGOtst],  'select active,created_at,city,total_xp from 
   content.users' )

I'm sure there's other ways to go about this. I was having some issues last week with a similar query and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. it works: `select * from MONGOtst...users` after doing steps copied from another topic:

> Found the answer here. Now I can the three dot notation query. Thanks
>
> http://www.sparkalyn.com/2008/12/invalid-schema-error/
>
> Go to the provider options screen In SQL Server you can see the list
>   of providers in a folder above the linked server (assuming you have
>   appropriate permissions). Right click on MSDASQL and go to properties.
>   In SQL Server, the provider options button is in the dialog box where
>   you create the linked server. Check the box that says “level zero
>   only”

2. also work after updating field description 'decimal' -> 'float64'